# Calling back into a native application from Java, via JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, function-pointers

So I built this C library. It calls Java methods via the JNI, everything works fine. But how can I call back from Java into my C application?

I imagine the following: I *do* have a function, I take its address, I have a function pointer. I pass the pointer to Java (for example as a callback, an event handler, or anything). How can I call that function from within Java?

Is there maybe a method to dynamically and explicitly bind a `native void method();` to a function pointer or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there maybe a method to dynamically and explicitly bind a native void method(); to a function pointer or something?

Yes there is! You can use [RegisterNatives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833) to dynamically bind Java methods with C/C++ functions.

To change implementation you can first call UnregisterNatives followed by a new call to RegisterNatives.

Comment: To obtain the function signatures required for `RegisterNatives` use the `javah` command on the classes that have native methods.